# How will Roslyn help me in avoiding a recompile to deploy changes to my ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am a little confused about the new Roslyn C# compiler.

In the beginning I assumed that this new compiler would make it possible to make changes to C# code in my ASP.NET MVC web site, and afterwards see these changes in a browser without ever have to rebuild the project/solution.

However doing some more reading, especially the new information, I am now so sure any more.

Is it possible, using Roslyn, to make changes to C# code within e.g. controller class and not having to build the project and still be able to see the changes?

Comment: Change C# code do not compile it and get changed binaries? That would be a cool trick. No Roslyn is part of a compiler so you can change the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) with full source infos before it is compiled to IL.

Comment: You want to recompile the binaries without a compiler. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: You're looking for ASP.Net vNext.

Comment: Yes I want to compile without having to compile!!! I know its asp.net vnext, but I have been reading different information about what exactly Roslyn will be able to do, hence I have become confused.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Roslyn can enable you to do this, but I suggest letting the ASP.NET Team do the hard work as part of ASP.NET vNext.

From the [Scott Hanselman's Blog Post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETVNext.aspx) on it (emphasis his):

> With the next version of ASP.NET **you get the power and throughput of
>   the .NET runtime plus the "Roslyn" compiler-as-a-service for a
>   "no-compile compile."** That means means during development time you can
>   just change your C# classes and hit Refresh in the browser. It's the
>   power of .NET with the dynamism of a refresh-and-go development
>   experience.

Comment: Hi Dave thanks for your answer. I think it was in fact the article with scott you have referred to where I got the information from. So in short what you/scott are saying is that I should wait for the next version of Roslyn (ASP.NET vNext) where it will be possible?

Comment: Wait for the "vNext" version of ASP.net, that should have the features you need.

Comment: @userSamarHTC ASP.Net vNext is the next version of Microsoft's web stack on the .Net platform, it will use the Roslyn C#/VB.Net compiler to enable features like the "no-compile compile" described here. It is *not* the next version of Roslyn, or any other compiler.