# Asp.Net 5 project hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to host a web application created in VS 2015 Preview with Asp.Net 5 Starter Web. I set Debug target to Web, I hit F5 and klr console is starting and and I am able to load application in browser, at specified port.

The problem is, when I change something in code (in a controller, or even in a cshtml view) and save, the klr server stops and console closes. 
Is this the intended behavior? Or should I be able to save and refresh, as Roslyn compiler works?

Comment: I guess Roslyn main thing is to do code analysis while you expect build refresh. What you are getting is intended behaviour as per my understanding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984030/how-will-roslyn-help-me-in-avoiding-a-recompile-to-deploy-changes-to-my-asp-net - Hanselman says that Roslyn should do that in next vNext version. Possibly not in this beta version. My main problem is that I also cannot host my app in IIS neither as it have to be published (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325264/asp-net-5-project-hosting-on-iis/27330403#27330403), so I have to stop it, build it and start it again, anytime I make a change, and this is very uncomfortable. Do you have any solution to run ASP.NET 5 application while you develop it?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'm afraid you have to work with IIS Express to get the "save and refresh" work for you. I think that's the default way when you create an asp.net 5 project in VS 2015 preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is how I managed it:

1. Installed KVM (http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/getting-started-with-asp-net-vnext-by-setting-up-the-environment-from-scratch)
2. Added "nodemon": "1.2.1" to package.json and restored nodemon package
3. Opened cmd, go to app directory and type **nodemon --exec "K.cmd web" -e cs,json** (-e tells nodemon which type of files to watch - I don't want all kind of files, since js, css etc are reloaded on refresh anyway).

   X:\Support\AspNet5\Test>nodemon --exec "K.cmd web" -e cs,json

   18 Dec 14:57:25 - [nodemon] v1.2.1

   18 Dec 14:57:25 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`

   18 Dec 14:57:25 - [nodemon] watching: *.*

   18 Dec 14:57:25 - [nodemon] starting `K.cmd web`

   [INFORMATION:Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener.MessagePump] Start

   Started
4. Edit a cs file - looking back to cmd window

   18 Dec 14:59:40 - [nodemon] restarting due to changes...

   [INFORMATION:Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener.MessagePump] Stop

   18 Dec 14:59:41 - [nodemon] starting `K.cmd web`

   [INFORMATION:Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener.MessagePump] Start

   Started
5. Refresh the browser

Hope this helps